# Including line breaks in HTML attributes

Tags: html

I have an HTML textarea with a "placeholder" attribute that includes the code for a line break, `&\#10;`. It works fine on Chrome, but the line break is ignored on other browsers. What is causing this inconsistency, and how do I work around it?

Comment: Take a look at this page <a>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909888/is-there-any-ascii-character-for-br<a>

Comment: I can't include a <br> tag in an HTML attribute.

Comment: Instead of the line break thing, use `\n` as new line in your placeholder. it's definite to work across browsers.

Comment: That just displays a literal "\n".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Include the line break naturally with the keyboard enter? Like it is shown in this image, click to see it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9M4W.png)

If it does not work, try inserting your place holder text via javascript?
See [Insert line break inside placeholder attribute of a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312623/insert-line-break-inside-placeholder-attribute-of-a-textarea)

Comment: A literal line break only seems to work in the same browsers as `&\#10;`- In Firefox and Safari, it's just ignored.

The other answer you linked to mentioned that the spec forbids line break characters in the placeholder text, so I guess it's Chrome that's non-compliant. That's quite frustrating. That other thread included some workarounds through, so I can use one of those.

Comment: yup. guess it has to be worked around. until the major browsers arrived in the future to support the same standards.