# Echo empty space as html char

Tags: php, html

I have a string `90001 90002`. I need to see which html special char is represented in the empty space. (It could be an empty space - `&nbsp;` or it could be a textual line-break masquerading as a space in HTML [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33909965/5432834). Maybe other possibilities that I'm not aware of..)

I would like to echo a string and show the empty spaces as html char (e.g. `$result = "90001&nbsp;90002"`).

I've tried using [html_entities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) but that doesn't cover spaces. Also neither does [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).
How would I go about doing this?
If possible I would like a purely PHP & html solution. If necessary - CSS. And if impossible otherwise, javascript will have to do..

Comment: Can you use JavaScript for this?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks for your answer... Sorry, I didn't specify what I would like. I've updated the question..

Comment: That's the best I can do... :) Will try finding other solutions for you, if possible.

Comment: if u have html tag u can directly use it ,or u can use $result=<pre>90001&nbsp;90002</pre> . it should work

Comment: @Ben There's another way... Hey, you can use this format. Get the HTML of the div and put it as text?

Comment: @PraveenKumar That sounds good - how would I do that? Anyway, so far - only you have the right idea of what I need. Why is everyone else misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @Ben Just trying to get it working in my answer. Wait...

Comment: @Ben Updated... Check...

Comment: @Ben Let me know if it works for you. I am waiting, or if should I get you a different solution?

Comment: @PraveenKumar on a quick test it wasn't working. I'll test it more thoroughly when I have more time. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben Sure... In the meantime, I'll keep checking... Holiday time - so couldn't spend much after this time.

Answer (score 3):

Just an out-of-box thinking. I had the same issue but looked into using JavaScript's `encodeURIComponent()` function:

```js
$(function () {
  $("div").html(function () {
    return encodeURIComponent($(this).html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>90001 90002</div>
```

Used jQuery as I am kinda lazy. You can do the same in JavaScript this way:

```html
<div>90001 90002</div>
<script>
  var div = document.querySelector("div");
  div.innerHTML = encodeURIComponent(div.innerHTML);
</script>
```

Just letting you know that this is better to handle in client side than in the server side.

---

**Update 2:** Getting the HTML content and updating the text of the HTML:

```js
$(function () {
  $("div").text(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
      return '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';';
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>90001—90002</div>
```

Something like this...

Comment: Did you look at the output? Do you really want `%20` to be displayed?

Comment: **Echo the space as HTML character** - my solution answers, but the upvoted answer doesn't do a thing!

Comment: The question asks how to show it as an HTML entity `&nbsp;`, not a URL-encoded `%20`.

Comment: @Barmar I got it... Updated my answer. See if it is kinda right?

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$mystring = "90001 90002";

$mystring = str_replace(" ","&nbsp;",$mystring);

echo $mystring;

?>
```

**I hope it helps**

Comment: thanks! but i think you misunderstood the question. I'm not sure what the string will be. I am receiving it as an empty space and I need to print it to show what is there. (Your solution simply replaces the empty string with a character and then printing that chosen character..)

Comment: @Ben there is only java script that can you us for this

Answer (score -2):

```
function removeWhiteSpace($text)
{
  $text = preg_replace('/[\t\n\r\0\x0B]/', '', $text);
  $text = preg_replace('/([\s])\1+/', ' ', $text);
  $text = trim($text);
  return $text;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -3):

Editing the Answer :

if you need to do it using PHP , Use urlencode function , which would hep to resolve it

```
<?php
$query_string = 'foo=' . urlencode($foo) . '&bar=' . urlencode($bar);
echo '<a href="mycgi?' . htmlentities($query_string) . '">';
?>
```

But they have set backs which is mentioned in the notes section of the documentation.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

You can also use functions like htmlentities,rawurlencode in php .

if you want to use it in javascript , You can use escape function.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

Comment: Well, you are replacing the contents, while it is supposed to show the output as HTML Characters.

Comment: No I have just given snippets in order to determine the spaces and empty characters , Moreover the general usage has been represented as snippets here not the exact solution snippet.

Comment: It's nowhere related to what the question needs. They want to convert `ab cd` into `ab&nbsp;cd`... Did you get it?

Comment: If its no where related how do you determine there is a space between ab and cd , that's what my solution is It can be using regex , when you parse the string using the regex you would get the group and you can replace it with any character you need

Comment: ***I would like to echo a string and show the empty spaces as html char (e.g. $result = "90001&nbsp;90002").*** - did you read the question? No more argument from me. Enjoy the holidays.

Comment: Seriously, mate? After explaining you what the OP requires in the above comment? Anyway...